# question about a video recording cutting out at 4GB, vs continuing recording and a new file created. Phone is Moto G7 Power

Tags: video, video-recording

question about a video recording cutting out

I have two Moto phones.

One when I do a 30-35min video, and that about 4GB size, it continues recording but makes a new file.

Both are not using an SD card.

The phone that stops recording, is running Android 9, and is build number PPOS29.114-134-2  (was PPO29.80-27 but updated to PPOS29.114-134-2)

The phone that continues recording is running Android 10, and is build number QPOS30.52-29-7-6

The phone that stops recording, has, under about..Model and hardware.  Moto G7 Power.

The phone that continues recording, has, under about..Model and hardware. Moto G7 Power (XT-1955-4)

Both are updated as much as possible.. but Motorola doesn't seem to let them both update to Android 10.

I know the compression on an oppo phone I have is much better, its 30min Mp4s are a fraction of the size.  The Oppo compresses mp4s well and didn't hit any 3.7GB or 4GB limit. The oppo 30min file is only about 850MB! And my Oppo phone is Android 11. Anyhow, no question re my Oppo phone.

```
G:\vids\aug8th>
...

<DIR>          newermoto
<DIR>          oldermoto
<DIR>          oppo

09/08/2021  16:50  4,081,015,200 newer_notupd_moto\VID_20210809_161905581.mp4  (31min 45sec) 




09/08/2021  16:50     4,080,838,961 oldermoto\VID_20210809_161917546.mp4    (31min 24sec)
09/08/2021  16:53       416,864,956 oldermoto\VID_20210809_161917546_02.mp4  (3min 12sec)


09/08/2021  16:54     1,875,077,957 oppo\VID20210809161850.mp4   (35min 13sec)
```

What i'm wondering is, is it a difference between Android 9 and Android 10 that would fix it?

Not that that helps much at the moment since the phone that cuts out won't update to Android 10!

Both Motos are on only internal storage, neither have an SD card. So file system of an SD card isn't relevant here, as no SD card in the Motos.

I wonder if the Moto G7 Power that continues recording is a later model / better model of Moto G7 Power.

Comment: SD-Card formatted with FAT32 have a 4GB limit. As it is difficult to check the actual file-system where you have chosen to save the videos may be they always split the recorded videos to 4GB chunks?

Comment: @Robert A) I have no SD card in the phones as mentioned in the question and B) The 4GB limit isn't the issue here.. 'cos the issue is one phone stopped recording, but the other phone (also a Moto G7 Power), continued recording but created a new file.

Comment: For the European Union (an may be other region) there is another "tax" based limitation: For devices that can record more than 30 minutes videos they are considered as video recording cameras which are in a different (higher) tax group. Therefore some vendors limit video recording to 30 minutes on some devices. And the 4GB limit can still be an issue as the app doesn't know if there is such a limit or not.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter in your case, afaik even underlaying file system is ext4, still 4 GB file size limit applies to emulated storage (sdcardfs) for compatibility reasons with fat32